# How to get `help` of a function when using spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

My system is centos 7 with anaconda5.3.1 and  spyder 3.3.3
When I coding in spyder, I want to get help of how to use a function.
For example, I want to know how to use `read_sql` of `pandas`.In the Ipython console,I tried:

```
In [6]: read_sql?
Object `read_sql` not found.

In [7]: pandas.read_sql?
Object `pandas.read_sql` not found.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You need to import `pandas` first (with the command `import pandas`) to get the help of `pandas.read_sql`. Did you do that?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba,you mean import `pandas` in console?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant.